# Como receber um objeto JSON de uma url/dominio externo?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

Achei uma API da Loteria que me traz os dados do resultado de um sorteio da Lotofácil, mas não estou conseguindo acessar os dados do objeto JSON.

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json", function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
});
```

Mas o console do navegador me mostra esse erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Quando acesso diretamente a URL eu baixo o arquivo JSON normalmente, então gostaria de saber do que se trata esse erro e como fazer o chamado certo para receber esses dados.

Comment: você tentou usar o jsonp ?

Comment: Li sobre isso, mas fiquei em duvida na implementação pois só vi exemplo com POST e não com GET.

Comment: Com jsonp ele consegue acessar mas da outro erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json?callback=jQuery1110…82617&_=1414173731373&callback=jQuery111003546048323623836_1414173731372:1

Comment: Estive testando vários métodos outro dia para dar a volta nessa limitação e até achei um que funcionava em alguns sites. Como não funcionou no site que queria, deixei de lado; acho que era usando um proxy do Yahoo. Vou tentar localizar aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graças a resposta do Caffé, através do PHP consegui obter o objeto e seus valores, desta forma:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json');
$jsonDecode = (json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 5):

[Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434788/1274092) diz que código JavaScript é limitado pela política de segurança *[same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)*.

Ou seja, o que você está tentando fazer (obter conteúdo de outro domínio via JavaScript) é bloqueado pelo navegador.

Ainda segundo a mesma resposta, para que fosse possível este tipo de acesso você precisaria de uma configuração no domínio destino (*developers.agenciaideias.com.br*).

Ou seja: você não poderá obter este conteúdo a partir de JavaScript rodando no navegador. Você terá que obter no lado do servidor da tua aplicação e devolver para o teu usuário uma página pronta com o conteúdo.

Comment: Então se eu tentar via PHP por exemplo eu provavelmente conseguirei?

Comment: Se não houver nenhum bloqueio específico na aplicação destino (*developers.agenciaideias.com.br*) como por exemplo exigir autenticação que você não tenha, sim, conseguirá.

Comment: Sua dica matou a charada, recebi objeto via PHP e consegui captar as informações.

Answer (score 5):

É possível usar o [Yahoo Query Language](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) para driblar *alguns* casos de *Same-origin Policy*.

Exemplo:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
{
    q: 'select * from json where url="http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json"',
    format: "json"
},
function(data){
    if (data.query.results) {
        console.log('data',data.query.results.json)
    } else {
        console.error('no results')
    }
});
```

Imprime:

```
{
  "concurso": {
    "numero": "1122",
    "data": "ES",
    "cidade": "<span style=\"font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;\">Estimativa de Prêmio</span><br /><span style=\"color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 22px; font-weight:bold;\">R$</span> <span style=\"font-size: 22px; color:#911687; font-weight: bold;\">1.700.000,00</span><br /><span style=\"font-size: 11px;\">*para o próximo concurso, a ser realizado em 24/10/2014</span><br /><br />-<a href=\"javascript:imprimir_lotofacil(1122);\"><img src=\"/loterias/_images/button/btn_imprimir_resultadojogo.jpg\" width=\"148\" height=\"73\" border=\"0\" /></a>",
    "local": "Caminhão da Sorte",
    "numeros_sorteados": [
      "02",
      "03",
      "07",
      "10",
      "11",
      "12",
      "13",
      "14",
      "16",
      "19",
      "20",
      "21",
      "23",
      "24",
      "25"
    ],
    "premiacao": {
      "acertos_15": {
        "ganhadores": "4",
        "valor_pago": "428.378,51"
      },
      "acertos_14": {
        "ganhadores": "507",
        "valor_pago": "1.485,58"
      },
      "acertos_13": {
        "ganhadores": "19.267",
        "valor_pago": "15,00"
      },
      "acertos_12": {
        "ganhadores": "242.287",
        "valor_pago": "6,00"
      },
      "acertos_11": {
        "ganhadores": "1.252.543",
        "valor_pago": "3,00"
      }
    }
  },
  "proximo_concurso": {
    "data": "23",
    "valor_estimado": "20"
  }
}
```

<sub>**Referência**: [*How to scrape content from other sites using jQuery?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397294/1287812)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

O sistema de proteção dos navegadores não permite a troca de xml ou json de domínios diferentes, porem, permite o uso de chamadas "link" para script´s de javascript de URLs externas.
Usando jQuery com dataType do tipo "jsonp" ( com P );
Este formato informa o jQuery para usar um "truque" que "engana" o navegado ;-), pois, internamente a requisição é feita como sendo um "link" de script.
Tenho usado há um bom tempo e FUNCIONA!

```
{
jQuery.ajax({
        url  : 'http://www.respondePaginasWeb',
        data : 'cliente=eu&acao=getmenu',
        type : "GET",
        crossDomain  : "true",
        dataType     : "jsonp",
        contentType  : "application/json",
        success: function( menu ){
            console.log(menu);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa url é bloqueada aqui no trabalho, tenta algo desse tipo pra ver o que da:

```html
$.ajax({ 
  url:"http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/lotofacil/json", 
  type:"GET", 
  crossDomain: "true", 
  dataType: 'application/json', 
  success: function (d) { 
     console.log(d) 
  }
})
```

Comment: Adicionei um error: function(){ alert("erro")} e ele deu caiu no erro.

Comment: qual o erro? poderia postar?

Comment: Não consegui captar o erro. Tentei captar assim mas não mostrou nada: error: function(xhr, status, error) {   alert(xhr.responseText);}

Answer (score 0):

```js
testarApi();

function testarApi(){

  var token ="crie seu token"
  var sorteio = "";
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: "https://lotorapido1.websiteseguro.com/lotofacil?token="+token+"&sorteio="+sorteio,
    method:'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
       $('#target').html('loading....');
    },
    success: function (response) {
            $('#target').html(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $('#target').html("['error' => '"+error.statusText+"']");
        }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="target"></pre>

Aproveita e testa minha API BETA: https://lotorapido1.websiteseguro.com/
```

aproveita e testa minha API de loterias grátis: https://lotorapido1.websiteseguro.com